# Exp-resso store: coupon code including VAT

Tags: expresso-store, coupon-code

I just found out that the value of my coupon is without tax.
Just like all the products in the store.

However, i've sold the coupon code including tax, so there's something not quite right.

How can I let customers redeem a coupon code after taxes have been calculated?

Comment: By 'coupon code' are you referring to Store's 'Promo Codes'? These shouldn't be *sold* as such but rather present an option to the customer in the checkout allowing them to enter a code for a discount. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Why shouldn't they be sold? It's a nice gift... A personal gift, a personal code. The receiver of the gift can redeem the code...

Comment: It's not that they *shouldn't* but generally it's not the typical use case of a promo code. They're usually applied when checking out as part of a promotional offer which has been given out. Gift vouchers on the other hand are typically sold as presents for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promo codes in Store don't include tax, just like everything else. This makes it easier when setting them up in the backend (as others have suggested, the promo code system wasn't really designed with gift cards in mind since they have no ongoing balance, but you can certainly bend it to your will).

Assuming your store includes taxes on the front end, and your tax rate is 10% - then if you sell a $20 promo code, you need to save that in the database as $18.1818 so that your customers can use the pre-tax value to purchase products.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your Coupon/Promo code will be based upon what you setup in the CP, it doesn't make sense to have a $25 off promocode be $25 + 7% tax, the better solution would be to create the coupon code for $26.75.

Personally I think you would be better off using DevDemon's Credits module from the sounds of it.

Comment: Thanks, Credits however, is made for Cartthrob and Brilliant Retail. I'm using Exp-resso store